# jsr303 validation on a getMethod that throws an exception

Tags: java, validation

I have the following method

```
public class Invoice
{
    public String currency="USD";

    @NoNull
    public BigDecimal getTotal()
    {
        if ("USD".equals(this.currency))
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        else
           return new BigDecimal("1.00");
    }
}
```

The code throws an IllegalArgumentException() when I run it, which is fine. However, when I run a validation test, the checker crashes and throws a ValidationException. I would like to test to continue and report the method that throws exception as failing the validation test. As it stands, any method that throws an exception crashes the validation checker.

The validation checker is

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Invoice>> violations = validator.validate(this);
```

and it throws:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to access getTotal
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.ReflectionHelper.getValue(ReflectionHelper.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.getValue(MetaConstraint.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
    at com.salesfront.core.client.model.proxies.Invoice.getValidationErrors(Invoice.java:198)
    at com.salesfront.core.client.model.proxies.AccountingValidation.ValidateAccount(AccountingValidation.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.ReflectionHelper.getValue(ReflectionHelper.java:297)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.salesfront.core.client.model.proxies.Invoice.getTotal(Invoice.java:148)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Is the validation checker designed to catch exceptions?

Comment: The validation checker has two lines and I suspect it is not. Can you check my edit. I pasted the validation check code in it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Validator class but I think my answer may fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the reason why the validation checker crashes is because the exception thrown in your code is never caught. If you surrounded your code with a try/throw/catch block that specifically caught the exception and did something with it then that might fix your problem.

Comment: It does fixes the problem, but then it breaks the rest of the library which excepts an exception to be thrown under the right circumstances.

Comment: You may want to try to more understand the circumstances by either analyzing the code in the Library or just Google-ing it... Sorry I couldn't be much more help.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for your time!